# I Do not want a fixed navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want my navbar to scroll with the rest of the page.

I don't want any fancy style like disappearing i want it to be placed like other element of the page but i cant seem to achieve that with Bootstrap 4.

This is what it looks like:

[image] 
It's hiding other elements.

```
<nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar-example">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav ml-auto justify-content-center  ">
        <li>menu item 1 </li>
        <li>menu item 2 </li>
        <li>menu item 3 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your title of this question is _"I Do not want a fixed navbar"_ but then in your question you say _"I want my navbar to scroll with the rest of the page"_. If you want it to scroll with the rest of the page it needs to be fixed. So which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding style="position: relative !important;" to the html element.

Comment: thank you very much i have been looking for this since

Comment: fo sho homeslice